# Exception sending text string via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to send a string via bluetooth from my Nexus S to another android device.
The code is the following:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)
  item.getMenuInfo();
  if(item.getItemId() == 0)
  {
    BluetoothDevice selDev = pairedDevices.get(info.position);
    TelephonyManager tman = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    byte[] toSend = "a text".getBytes();
            try 
            {
                BluetoothSocket socket = selDev.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                      UUID.fromString("00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                out.write(toSend);

                return true;
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

but I get always this IO Exception: **java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected**

What's wrong?

Comment: have you first made connection with other bluetooth device?

Comment: I've a listview with paired/bounded device and than I have to send a string to one of them

Comment: You need to call `selDev .connect()`  That actually created the socket connection. But my problem is it fails on there and I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using secure connection solved my problem. But in your case you need to call `connect()` to initiate the connection.

```
//Just in case cancel any discovery as this slows everything down
selDev.CancelDiscovery();

//Try the secure method too. I found that worked for me.
BluetoothSocket socket = selDev.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                      UUID.fromString("00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

socket.Connect();

OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
```